# Angular - Real-Time fill an array from an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

Just a quick question thats answer can be really interesting to read for javascript & angular/typescript beginners:

Supposing that I have - for example - the Angular's tour of heroes "get Heroes" method:

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
    getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
            .pipe(
            tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
            catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
            );
    }
```

**How can I use this method to fill an array in real time while it's fetching data?**

I mean, if I've got a table containing more than 1000 heroes and i don't want to wait that front-end receives all data but I want to display them as i receive them, **is there any way to do this and filling an array of objects in real time while fetching data?**

By default, and based on my angular knowledge I would call this method from modules as follows:

```
getHeroes() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}
```

But this will fill my this.heroes array just once I'll get all of my data, with all of the problems related to big amounts of data download (such as slow loading times and low user friendly apps).

Should I use .map function? Or are there better ways to perform this action?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The way a classic HTTP request works is 1 request=1 response so there is no concept of a partial response that you could leverage in this scenario to accomplish this. Another option is that you have a live websocket that loads data continuously and your server is set up to deliver data in this fashion, in that case this could be accomplished with the scan operator without much trouble.  A third option is that you want to explicitly make several http requests for different portions of the list and manually combine them, this could also be accomplished, but this needs more detail to be asnwered.

Comment: @bryan60 Understood! Thanks! So I think the only way is to manage large datasource from server side in order to get a lower performance impact on my front-end side.

I think yours can be considered a good answer to my question

Comment: no matter what this will have some server set up to it.  Typical set up (for my apps) is to request a page of a large list and then have some kind of client side trigger to load more data (such as when the user scrolls to a certain position in a list or hits a next page button)

Comment: Consider using pagination here... Return chunks of heroes and certain metadata to get the next chunk.

Comment: For bryan60 and Lansana (I can't tag you both): feel free to copy and paste your comments as an answer below, they will get more visibility for other users. I will certainly vote up for them as useful answers, becasuse they both actually are!